# How to reorder keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in the form:

```
my_list = [{'a': 'Jane', 'b': 32}, {'a': 'Jack', 'b': 54}]
```

I want to re-order this to the form:

```
 new_dt = [{'b': 32, 'a': 'Jane'}, {'b': 54, 'a': 'Jack'}]
```

I have used the following code:

```
order_dict = ['b', 'a']

for dt in my_list:
    for k in order_dict:
        new_dt = my_list[k]
```

### Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-0d451ee34800> in <module>
      3 for dt in my_list:
      4     for k in order_dict:
----> 5         new_dt = my_list[k]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Why? Dictionaries and sets are colelctions without order - python from 3.7 uses input order but thats an implementation detail...

Comment: `my_list` is a list and `k` is a string. In `my_list[k]`, you cannot use a string as a list index.

Comment: @PatrickArtner part of the spec since 3.7

Comment: @SuperStormer - so what. Thats exactly what I said. but from a computerscience standpoint "order" is absolutely irrelevant for dictionaries - they are a O(1) access key value store thats unorderd. Sorting them is irrelevant. If you want them output in some kind of sort-order - simply do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a:

```
my_list = [{'a': 'Jane', 'b': 32}, {'a': 'Jack', 'b': 54}]
print([dict(sorted(x.items(),key = lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)) for x in my_list])
```

**The OUTPUT:**

```
[{'b': 32, 'a': 'Jane'}, {'b': 54, 'a': 'Jack'}]
```

**Explanation**

```
sorted(x.items(),key = lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
```

Here we are just sorting the items (keys and values) in the dictionary to get the order as required.

```
key = lambda x:x[0]
```

This component ensures that we are sorting based on the first element in items(essentially the key of dictionary)

We have reverse Set to true to get the desired sequence.